# How to change value in other file React

Tags: reactjs

How can I set use state in another file?
I mean, i want to set useState in file A, for example:

```
import './left_pane_style.css';
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {isLoggedCorrectly} from "../checkIsUserLogged";

const Left_pane = () =>{

    const [count, setCount] = useState('Test');

    function checkCookies(){
        isLoggedCorrectly()
    }

    return  <div className="left_container">
                <button className="asd">{count}</button>
            </div>
}

export default Left_pane;
```

And in the file B when i click on button, i want to change value in this: "const [count, setCount] = useState('Test');" useState in file A

Comment: By lifting the state up: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html *"Often, several components need to reflect the same changing data. We recommend lifting the shared state up to their closest common ancestor."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you would need to lift the state up. What that means is that you lift the `count` state to the closest `Parent` component that both `File A` and `File B` uses.

First, you would have a `Parent` component that uses both `File A` and `File B`. You would define the state in there and pass the values you need to the child components.

```js
// Parent
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FileA from "./FileA"
import FileB from "./FileB"

const Parent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <FileA count={count} />
      <FileB setCount={setCount} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

In `File A`, if you need to use the `count` of your state, you simply accept it as props and use it however you need.

```js
// File A
import React from "react";

const FileA = ({ count }) => {
  return <div>{count}</div>;
};

export default FileA;
```

In `File B`, you would accept `setCount` function as props which you could then use to set the state of `count` (which lives in the `Parent` component).

```js
// File B
import React from "react";

const FileB = ({ setCount }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Update Count</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FileB;
```

It's just an example code but I hope it gives you an understanding of how to use the same state between components.